# Show all ngForm Errors

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have big form with Angular 1.3. The Save Button is greyed out as long as the form is invalid (`myForm.$invalid`). Now I want a small Box at the bottom to display all invalid fields, so the users nows, what is wrong.

How can I bind all the errors and the fields which cause them?

So that you can for example see: "Username: Contains invalid characteres"

Comment: you need to show the errors right?

Comment: You can look at the object [`myForm.$error`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$error)

Comment: @NairAthul Well yes basically which input fields are causing the form to be invalid and why.

Comment: @George I found this, but it just lists me all errors but not which input field is causing which one

Comment: Actually you can get the field name from the error object, have a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eKNeicjIKybMxPJy8yPu?p=info) the only thing you need to make sure is that your fields have the `name` attribute on.

Comment: There are lot of ways to do that..you can highlight the elements with different color or also use the custom messages besides the element based on the type of valiadtion.